# Storing and printing array in C

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, macros, malloc

I'm studying structures and algorithms in C and I've been stuck trying to figure this example for quite few hours.
I'd be really glad if anyone can explain this in simple terms to me, since it's obviously flying above my head and my smooth brain can't comprehend it.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#define r(i,j) r[(i)*n+(j)]

int main()
{
  int *p, n, pom, i, j;
  long *r;
  FILE *d;

  d = fopen ("niz", "r");
  if (d == NULL)
    perror("Ne mogu otvoriti datoteku");

  for (n = 0; fscanf(d, "%d", &pom) == 1; n++);
  fseek (d, 0L, SEEK_SET);
  p = (int *) malloc (n * sizeof (int));

  if (p == NULL)
    perror("Nema dovoljno memorije za ucitati niz");

  for (n = 0; fscanf(d, "%d", &p[n]) == 1; n++);
  fclose (d);
  if ((r = (long *) malloc (n*n*sizeof(long))) == NULL)
    perror("Nema dovoljno memorije za rezultat");

  for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
  {
    r(0,j) = p[j];
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
      r(i,j) = r(i-1,j) * r(0,j);
  }
  free (p);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
      printf ("%10ld", r(i,j));
    printf ("\n");
  }

  d = fopen ("matrica", "wb");
  fwrite (&n, sizeof (int), 1, d);
  fwrite (r, sizeof (long), n*n, d);
  fclose (d);
  free (r);
  return 0;
}
```

This is basically what this code does, it reads few numbers from file, stores them and then prints it on screen in given array.
[image: This is what code does]

So what I don't understand here is how that #define block works, we've only ever got taught how it works in simplest terms like #define AGE 12, never even put calculations in it.

Now besides that, there are 2 for loop blocks at the end of code, one stores values and one prints them, now if only I could understand how it does it.
I've tried printing the numbers that it stores, and for variable 'j' I get correct numbers, from 1 to 6, and when I print r(i,j) I get 0 or random high number, so basically I don't understand how it even calculates them or what formula in #define has to do with it at all.

I would appreciate any kind of help since I'm stuck watching this code for too long now and my brain feels too smooth at this point because I'm not understanding it.

[image: Code in works]

So latest for loop that prints numbers is working perfectly, as can be seen, but above it I've put 2 printf functions to check if numbers are matching and figure out how it works, yet I can't figure it out at all.

Variable 'j' is printing out 6 numbers as it should, although from 0 to 5, but down below it's printing from 1 to 6, but basically it kind of works and I understand that one.

Just below it variable 'r' is printing 0 or some random high number, but when it prints it in latest for block, it does so as it should, and this one I can't understand at all.

Comment: Macros are like simple string replacement. `#define r(i,j) r[(i)*n+(j)]` means "please replace `r(A,B)` appear after this with `r[(A)*n+(B)]`".

Comment: `#define r(i,j)` is called a *function-like macro*. There should be plenty of info and examples on that.

Comment: If you are on Linux, but I see you are not :P, I suggest to use gcc -E to run preprocessing phase only. Then look on the .i code which is the result. It might be messy, but main function should be human-readable. I'm not sure what tool you are using, but I think you can stop building process on preprocessing too.

Comment: Thanks to all of you too, I've finally figured out the first part with #define function after being dumbfounded by it for too long now, if anyone wants to try and help me with second part, I've made an edit to my question. ♥

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#define AGE 12` and `#define r(i,j) r[(i)*n+(j)]` work in the same way.

In your program, the code matching `AGE` wioud be replaced by `12`, the same way, the code maching `r(i,j)` will be replaced by `r[(i)*n+(j)]`, `i` and `j` being the values passed as argument of the function-like macro.

Let's say `i` is 1, `j` is 2, and `n` is 5, `r(i,j) = r(i-1,j) * r(0,j)`

Would be equivalent to:

```
r[(1)*5 + (1)] = r[(1-1)*5 + (2)] * r[(0)*5 + (2)]
```

Wich will amount to:

```
r[6] = r[2] + r[2]
```

The array element with index 6 will be assigned the result of the sum of the values stored in array element with index 2.

About the what the function does, it's just array arithmetic to use a 1D array as if it was a 2D array, avoiding the need to use an actual 2D array to store/print the values.

If you replace the print loop, with something like:

```
for (i = 0; i < n * n; i++) { 
    printf("%10ld", r[i]); 
}
```

You'll see the same values but printed as a 1D array, which is really what it is.

The printed seemingly random numbers, are just a hint that you are accessing the array ouside its bounds invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That answered my first question perfectly, can't believe I got stuck on that for this long, damn. I've edited my question for trying to figure out second part, if you know anything I'd be glad if you can help. Thanks again man!

Comment: @AdiKešetović, glad to help, note that you should ask a new question regarding your new doubts, as per the site guidelines, *one question per post*, I will be glad to answer it, if I'm around, if not, I'm sure someone will. Don't forget to post a minimal reproducible example that can be copied and ran by users, that includes the hardcoded array values, or the contents of the file.

Comment: Sure thing, thanks man, I'll try to figure it out a little bit more and if I don't I'll make a new question. :)

Comment: @AdiKešetović, that is a good mindset, trying learning things yourself first, I mean. Hint: this is just simple arithmetic to print a 1D array as if it was a 2D array. If you test print the array `for (i = 0; i < n * n; i++) { printf("%10ld", r[i]); }` you'll see that the values on the array are printed, but in a single line.

Comment: I figured it out finally, took me a while and it was mostly because of missed {} on for loop that I was trying to print out the number it was storing. Thanks again for your help, I tried to upvote but couldn't because I need 15 reputation, forgot that you can accept answer, I'll do it now! :)

Comment: @AdiKešetović you can now, you have 25 ;) Anyway, good luck with your learning, maybe some day you can come here and spread your knowledge.